# Is my CPU dead?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, amd-ryzen

Last week I bought all new components to build a new computer. When I put it all together, there was a few problems. First, there was no post beep or sound confirmation at all. I thought it was the motherboard because the LED's on the motherboard weren't working, so I bought a new motherboard (MSI B350 Gaming Plus). After getting it all set up again, there was no post beep but the LED's were working, and the chances of 2 dead MOBO's is unlikely.

Notes:
- CPU fan is running
- GPU is running/fans are working
- All wires are plugged in correctly
- CPU is the Ryzen 5 1500x

Is there any was I am missing something or is my CPU dead?

Comment: How many watts is your power supply?  What CPU and GPU?  It might be as simple as not having enough power.  There should be a BIOS reset pin,jumper, button on your mobo, try using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: mobo]

From the manual downloaded from msi!

Unplug your video card and connect your monitor to one of the video connectors shown here.  See if the mobo is using the onboard graphics and not the GPU.

See page 26 about loading the memory in the correct slots DIMMA2 is the 1st slot your supposed to populate.

[image: reset bios]

[image: status leds]
What is the status of the status leds?

Comment: After looking at the LED lights, the CPU one (top) is lit up. Unfortunately I think it was also lit up on the old motherboard, so I bought a new motherboard for nothing and may have accidentally damaged the old one taking off the CPU to switch it out (dribbled small amounts of thermal paste on the MOBO)

Comment: How about the other LEDs?  Dribbling a small amount of thermal paste **should** have **no** effect on it.

Comment: I havent checked the old MOBO since I took it out, but the new MOBO only shows the CPU light on, and on the old MOBO there was only one light which I assume was the CPU light

Comment: Put 1 memory stick in DIMM A2, and see if that changes the leds.  Remove the rest.

Comment: Nope, still the red CPU light. I think at this point it's narrowed down to the CPU, shame but that sort of thing happens.

Comment: Before you run off and change your CPU how big is your PSU?  I had a probably where the CPU light was on and it turned out my PSU was dead or underperforming.

Comment: 400W PSU, I checked and it was plenty enough to run what I need, I even have the GPU removed and it doesn't work.

Comment: After removing the GPU did you connect your monitor to the onboard graphics port?

Comment: Yes I did, and nothing changed

Comment: I would still recommend trying a different PSU first, maybe try 500w.  I know it shouldn't need that much, but maybe the PSU is defective.  Also I have seen some manufacturers cheat on the specs so you may not even have the advertised 400w.